# Why can't our Exchange mail server find DNS records for a single (external) domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange

We have a lot of outgoing mail every day. This all works fairly flawlessly.

unfortunately, there is 1 domain we can't send to. The error given in Queue viewer `"451 4.4.0 DNS query failed. The error was: DNS query failed with error InfoNoRecords"`.

When I NSlookup the domain, our Mail server finds nothing. When I NSlookup from a domain computer or from a website like CentralOps, their domain and records seem to be working like normal.

Does anyone know why no DNS records for said domain can be found on our Mail server?

Comment: do you use the same DNS server on the exchange server and on the domain computers?

Comment: Hi mzhaase, sorry for the late response. Yes we do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the remote domain has an issue.

You haven't said what records you can see, so you need to do a specific lookup for the MX records - just seeing domain records for a domain is not enough. I own about 20 domains, but you do an MX lookup on most of them you get nothing.

Every case I have seen with this error it has been a problem with the remote domain. Never Exchange. If it was Exchange then it would be more widespread.

Comment: This is the acid test: Your email server can't send email to _anyone_? Probably your server. Your email server can send email to anyone _except_ that one server over there in the corner? Then either your email server and everyone else's happens to be misconfigured in the exact same way and the guy running the email server over there in the corner is the only person in the world doing it right, or they've misconfigured their server. Which seems most likely?